# libpq.so.5 file is not available while installing postgres-12

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I have installed postgres-11 already on my machine. libpq.so.5 file is there already into /usr/pgsql-11/lib directory. However, now I need to upgrade to 12. I ran below commands:

```
   yum install postgresql12-server postgresql12 -y
```

Then, I go with initialize step and got below error:

```
   /usr/pgsql-12/bin/postgresql-12-setup initdb
   Initializing database ... failed, see /var/lib/pgsql/12/initdb.log
  
   cat /var/lib/pgsql/12/initdb.log
   /usr/pgsql-12/bin/initdb: error while loading shared libraries: 
   libpq.so.5: cannot open shared 
   object file: No such file or directory
```

Then,I started searching for this file into my postgresql-12 directory and didn't find any file there. However, this file was present into pgsql-11 directory structure:

```
   cat /var/lib/pgsql/12/initdb.log
  /usr/pgsql-12/bin/initdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: 
   cannot open shared 
   object file: No such file or directory
```

As per available searches - created a link like below to avoid the error:

```
    ln -s /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5
```

And after this I was able to initialize the db successfully and perform upgrade. But, when I tried to connect psql after starting services for 12 after upgrade- I got below error:

```
    sudo su - postgres -c "psql"
    psql (12.3)
    psql: symbol lookup error: psql: undefined symbol: PQgssEncInUse
```

After this , I'm stuck at this error and unable to connect psql. I have below 2 questions now:

1. Why libpq.so.5 file is not available into postgres-12 directory structure?
2. How to avoid PQgssEncInUse error or what is causing this error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?  What repository are you installing from?

Comment: @jjanes - I'm using centos and  here is the path for repo: rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

Comment: CentOS7?  Did you follow https://yum.postgresql.org/news/new-repo-rpms-released/ ?

Comment: Thanks. I did a fresh installation after removing all old installations. Now, it's been fixed

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, to resolve this, I removed `libpq-11.5-1` package as well along with `postgres`:

```
yum remove libpq-* postgresql-*
```

and then installed postgresql-12.17

```
yum install postgresql-12.17
```